# How to have Media Recorder working on ios devices?

Tags: ios, typescript, solid-js

I have a component that records user and previews him.
I've already addressed the chrome bug, but yet another appears.
The timer doesn't run on ios and the stop button doesn't work.
It seems media recorder is supported for ios devices (greater than version 14) as per mdn.
How to fix this please ?

```
export default function RecordVideo() {
  const [state, setState] = createSignal<State>("idle");
  const [count, setCount] = createSignal<number>(0);
  const [message, setMessage] = createSignal<string>("start recording");

  let chunks: Blob[] = [];
  let preview: { srcObject: MediaStream };
  let recorder: MediaRecorder;
  let repairedVideo: Blob;
  let interval: number;

  const startRecording = async () => {
    try {
      const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        audio: true,
        video: true,
      });
      setState("recording");
      preview.srcObject = stream;
      recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, { mimeType: "video/webm" });
      recorder.ondataavailable = ({ data }) => chunks.push(data);
      recorder.start();
      recorder.onstop = async () => {
        repairedVideo = await fixWebmDuration(
          new Blob([...chunks], { type: "video/webm" })
        );
        chunks = [];
        setState("stopped");
        preview.srcObject.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
        clearInterval(interval);
      };
      interval = window.setInterval(() => setCount(prev => prev + 1), 1000);
    } catch ({ message }: any) {
      setMessage(message);
    }
  };

  const deleteRecording = () => {
    setCount(0);
    setState("idle");
  };

  const downloadRecording = () =>
    Object.assign(document.createElement("a"), {
      href: URL.createObjectURL(repairedVideo),
      download: "arms",
      type: "video/mp4",
    }).click();

  return (
    <section>
      <Switch>
        <Match when={state() === "idle"}>
          <div onClick={startRecording}>
            {message()}
          </div>
        </Match>
        <Match when={state() === "recording"}>
          <div>
            <video
              class="w-96 rounded-2xl shadow -scale-x-100"
              ref={preview! as HTMLVideoElement}
              playsinline
              autoplay
              muted
            />
            <div>
              <span>{formatCount(count())}</span>
              <button onClick={() => recorder.stop()}>
                stop
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </Match>
        <Match when={state() === "stopped"}>
          <div>
            <video
              class="w-96 rounded-2xl shadow"
              src={URL.createObjectURL(repairedVideo!)}
              playsinline
              controls
            />
            <div>
              <button onClick={deleteRecording}>
                delete
              </button>
              <button onClick={downloadRecording}>
                download
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </Match>
      </Switch>
    </section>
  );
}
```

Thanks you!

Comment: sorry snnsnn, I was kinda annoyed with chrome issue tbh, really it's been 7 years and still no change. Is your article about fixing this ? sorry...